# How do I duplicate an object in Verold?

Tags: verold

I am trying to duplicate an object every time I click it in Verold. I have attached the Object Picker to the scene and successfully triggered a function which prints to the console.

I've tried this code but I get a Type Error - can't read property of undefined.

```
var xxx = this.getEntity().clone();
var threeDataxxx = xxx.getThreeData();
threeDataxxx.position.x += Math.random() * 5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clone()` method is asynchronous (because the same method would be used if you were creating persistent copies of your objects on the server). This function, like many functions in the Verold API, takes an 'options' object as a parameter. In here, you need to specify the 'success' callback method like in the following example. Once you have the clone, you then need to add it to the scene hierarchy using the `addChild()` method. This will automatically trigger the cloned object to load.

```
var parent = this.getEntity().getParentObject();
this.getEntity().clone( {
    success: function( newEntity ) {
        parent.addChild( newEntity );
        var position = newEntity.getPosition();
        position.x += Math.random() * 10;
        newEntity.setPosition( position.x, position.y, position.z );
    }
});
```

The multiple steps are useful because you may want to clone several objects and have them ready to add to the scene at a later time.

And, of course, if you don't require the cloned object to have components or any of the other functionality of a VeroldObject, you can always just get the `threeData` and then use Three.JS's clone() method.

Hope that helps.